# Double foreach loop in node child (TikZ tree)

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees

I'm trying to typeset probability trees with TikZ, with many branches, so I would prefer to avoid full typing. I cannot figure out how to make kind of a double loop. Here is an example of what I currently have :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=60mm},level 2/.style={sibling distance=10mm}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(0){root}[grow'=right]
    child{ node{B} foreach \n/\l in {4/B, 3/R, 1/J} { child foreach \i in {1,...,\n} { node{\l} } } }
    child{ node{R} \foreach \n/\l in {4/B, 3/R, 1/J} { child foreach \i in {1,...,\n} { node{\l} } } ; }
%    child{ node{G} \foreach \n/\l in {4/B, 3/R, 1/J} { \foreach \i in {1,...,\n} { child node{\l} } ; } ; }
    child{ node{J} child foreach \i in {1,...,4} { node{B} }
                   child foreach \i in {1,...,3} { node{R} }
                   child {node{J}}
         } ;               
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The suitable result, the one I want to get at each node of the 2nd level, is this of the last node, with 8 branches from the node "J" of the 1st level (bottom of the tree). The preceding codes don't give what I expected to get, or don't compile (the commented out line).

If someone have ideas, thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: That we can more easy imagine, what you like to obtain, please add to your question a sketch of desired tree.

Comment: I must have not be clear enough, sorry. I want 8 branches connected to any 1st level node,  like the J node at the bottom of the tree.

Comment: one sketch=1000 words. See, if my answer reproduce what you like to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my opinion is better to use `forest` package than use loops in `tikz` tree design. Since it is not clear (to me, at least), how your tree should looks,
i partly reconstruct it from your code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
    grow' = 0,
    s sep = 1mm,
    l sep = 9mm,
            }
[root
    [B
        [B][B][B][B
                    [R][R][R]
                 ]
    ]
    [R,fit=band, before computing xy={s/.average={s}{siblings}}
        [B][B][B][B
                    [R][R][R]
                 ]
    ]
    [J
        [B][B][B][B][R][R][R][J]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or if you in above MWE delete option`before computing xy={s/.average={s}{siblings}}`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I will test. My ultimate need is to create a command that will allow me to easily create "trees to count issues" rather to "trees with probabilities on branches".

Comment: I would really like to be able to construct the tree with foreach loop. My goal is to be able to create, say, 64 issues tree, so 8x8 final branches, without the need to declare manually each branch. That's why I insisted on loops, in my MWE and in the title... I tried to mix forest and \foreach, but no more success.

Comment: @natsirt, than you need to wait on other answer. From comparison my solution and your desired one, is clear that mine have shorter code, is more clear and easier maintain. But, as you wish. Good luck!

Comment: Yep, agree with you indeed. Thanks. And I've just realized that forest has built-in loop capabilites, though I just cannot figure out how to use it right now ;-) !